# How to simplify REST controllers with same methods and different headers?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, gradle

I have one Java REST API which is used by 2 different consumers. By default REST principles my API should define the names of request headers. But now I have not common situation. Consumers use different security layer which provides different headers which means same parameter in both ways.

**Example method:** *(not real code)*
For 1st consumer:

```
@PostMapping("/number")
Integer getNumber(@RequestHeader("no") String number, @RequestBody User user) {
    /*...*/
}
```

For 2nd consumer:

```
@PostMapping("/number")
Integer getNumber(@RequestHeader("number") String number, @RequestBody User user) {
    /*...*/
}
```

I have up to 10 methods in one controller and they should be with same name and logic, but different header. The request path prefix could be different.

---

### Question:

> > **How to simplify REST controller and don't create 2 different controllers with same methods and same logic?**

---

### What I tried:

I tried several examples to create one controller with 2 different interfaces with same methods, but different mapping.

### Example:

**Controller class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="/application")
@Api(tags = {"application"})
public class ApplicationController implements AppMapping1, AppMapping2 {

    @Override
    public Integer getNumber(String number, User user) {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

**First interface**

```
interface AppMapping1 {

    @PostMapping("/num")
    Integer getNumber(@RequestHeader("num") String number, @RequestBody User user);
}
```

**Second interface**

```
interface AppMapping2 {

    @PostMapping("/number")
    Integer getNumber(@RequestHeader("number") String number, @RequestBody User user);
}
```

### Result:

> > Controller maps only with the first interface. So `http://.../application/num` works fine, but `http://.../application/number` - gets `404` error code. That means Java Spring-Boot doesn't have such functionality. Need some more ideas.

Project developed with `Java 8`; `spring-boot:2.1.1.RELEASE`; `gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers) , If we're not sure which headers will be present, or we need more of
>   them than we want in our method's signature, we can use the
>   @RequestHeader annotation without a specific name.

You have a few choices for variable type: a `Map`, a `MultiValueMap` or an `HttpHeaders` object.

Sample

```
@PostMapping("/number")
public Integer getNumber(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {

    if (Optional.ofNullable(headers.get("no")).isPresent()){
        //...
    }
    else if (Optional.ofNullable(headers.get("number")).isPresent())
    {
        //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not maintenance friendly to repeat the same block of code twice or more times just to receive the same input with different names (`number` and `no`). Instead, it is advisable to read all the headers and traverse through it to fetch input using different names.

**Sample Code**

```
@PostMapping("/number")
public Integer getNumber(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
    String number = headers.containsKey("number") ? headers.get("number") : headers.get("no");
    if(Objects.isNull(number)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Number input not received from header!");
    }

    // relevant processing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-request-header.html

> Avoid ambiguity by using @RequestMapping(headers = ....)
>
> We can fix the ambiguity similar to @RequestParam where we used
> 'params' . In case of @RequestHeader we can define related headers in
> @RequestMapping annotation.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("trades")
public class TradesController {

   @RequestMapping(headers = "User-Agent")
    public String handleAllTradesRequests (@RequestHeader("User-Agent") String userAgent,
                                           Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "all trades requests, User-Agent header  : "
                                                                    + userAgent);
        return "my-page";
    }

    @RequestMapping(headers = "From")
    public String handleRequestByFromHeader (@RequestHeader("From") String from,
                                             Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "trade request by From header  : " + from);
        return "my-page";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. That is not an answer for same header with different names handling

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `@RequestHeader` annotation and consider doing the following:

```
    @PostMapping("/number")
    Integer getNumber(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody User user) {
      String number = request.getHeader("num");
      if(number == null){
         number = request.getHeader("number");
      }    
      /*...*/
    }
```

If you want a cleaner approach, consider creating a util class that takes the `HttpServletRequest` object and returns the desired header value.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add the `HttpServletRequest` as an argument of your single controller and do some logic with the header map provided by the `HttpServletRequest` object.

If you want to see a full example take a look [here](https://github.com/gemini-projects/gemini/blob/1984fe019bd16420a31cf9dad017cb9ac2007540/gemini-core/src/main/java/it/at7/gemini/api/RestAPIController.java). I have implemented I single controller that wraps all my logic accordingly to headers/methods and so on. You can customize the logic as you want with the `HttpServletRequest`.